# Wrap two texture over a plane?

Tags: android, opengl-es, mapping, textures

How do you wrap two textures over a plane? I think I did it, but the texture is filling the whole object not just the sliver I want it to.

Any help is appreciated
~Aedon

```
InputStream is = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.woodtexture1);
InputStream is2 = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.bandtest);
Bitmap bitmap = null;
Bitmap b2 = null;
try {
        //BitmapFactory is an Android graphics utility for images
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
        b2 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is2);
} finally {
//Always clear and close
try {
    is.close();
    is2.close();
    is = null;
    is = null;
} catch (IOException e) {}
}

    //Generate one texture pointer...
    gl.glGenTextures(1, textures, 0);
    //...and bind it to our array
    gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);

    //Create Nearest Filtered Texture
    gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL10.GL_NEAREST);
    gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR);

    //Different possible texture parameters, e.g. GL10.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE
    gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL10.GL_REPEAT);
    gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL10.GL_REPEAT);

    //Use the Android GLUtils to specify a two-dimensional texture image from our bitmap
    GLUtils.texImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);

    //Generate one texture pointer...
    gl.glGenTextures(1, textures, 0);
    //...and bind it to our array
    gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);

    //Create Nearest Filtered Texture
    gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL10.GL_NEAREST);
    gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR);

    //Different possible texture parameters, e.g. GL10.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE
    gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL10.GL_ONE);
    gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL10.GL_ONE);
    GLUtils.texImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);
    GLUtils.texImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, b2, 0);
```

Comment: Some code of what you tried would be helpful, then we can see what the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am unsure if this is what you want - but if you want your texture to cover only part of your object, use `glTexCoordPointer` to set texture coordinates for your object.

Some examples of your actual draw code would be great, though.

Comment: No you seem to have nailed it for me thanks. Sorry to ask this to but how do you use glTextCoordPointer? I can't find decent documentation for GL at all.

Comment: See http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glTexCoordPointer.xml - you use it in much the same way you would glVertexCoordPointer